# data.table conditional search

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

How to search in data.table by condition?

I have a table for, let's say, users which contains user ip + a table of ip ranges from http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/csv/. I would like to get a country for each user. The problem is that in order to find a country you need to split the IP to tokens and apply some formula to get an integer value representing the address. Then you need to find a row where that value fits in range.

I managed to do that with data.frame's but it is very slow..

```
extract.country <- function(code) {
  geo[(geo['V3']<=code & code<=geo['V4'])][6]
}
```

There are 93100 ip addresses ranges and relatively same number of users. But it seems to take about

```
   user  system elapsed 
   17.109   1.144  20.649
```

to process 100 users on my machine. Which will be about 5 hours to process all of them.

That is how my & geoIP datasets are look like:

```
> head(dat)
                   V2            V26
1 2014-03-01 14:06:59  86.183.184.19
2 2014-03-01 23:50:02  86.112.53.139
3 2014-03-01 15:07:02    5.69.149.65
4 2014-03-01 14:27:18 218.186.19.230
5 2014-03-01 13:08:31   86.0.151.153
6 2014-03-01 23:18:00    79.148.42.6
> 
> head(geo)
        V1         V2       V3       V4 V5        V6
1  1.0.0.0  1.0.0.255 16777216 16777471 AU Australia
2  1.0.1.0  1.0.3.255 16777472 16778239 CN     China
3  1.0.4.0  1.0.7.255 16778240 16779263 AU Australia
4  1.0.8.0 1.0.15.255 16779264 16781311 CN     China
5 1.0.16.0 1.0.31.255 16781312 16785407 JP     Japan
6 1.0.32.0 1.0.63.255 16785408 16793599 CN     China
```

Where for each IP I calculate an int value, like

```
[1] 1454880787 1450194315   88446273 3669627878 1442879385 1335110150
```

I wanted to improve the performance with a data.table as columns might be indexed and performance is really good for exact search. But I can't figure out how to make a conditional search with that.

Or, is there any other way to do that with R?

Comment: It's readable in no more than 15 mins and gives a good start : [link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf)

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel thank you. I've read that. Unfortunately, there is no information about conditional search. Most examples are searches like `DT[J("R","h")` which is equal to `DF[DF$x=="R" & DF$y=="h",]`

Comment: `geo[V3 <= code & code <= V4, V6]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
dt<-data.table(num=c(1,2,3,1,3,4,6,7,7,7,8,3), let=(rep(c("A","B","C"), each=4)))
```

then:

```
dt[num > 1 & let == "B"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to R, so could be wrong. It seems that rows are sorted by values in V3 column (if not - sort them), so you can use fast binary search.

```
extract.country <- function(code) {
    geo[[findInterval(code,geo$V3),"V6"]]
}
```